# Zookeeper DX Strategy

Tags: zookeeper-dx

I'm sure this is a super low-fi game to be asking about here, however I'm having a hard time finding info.
I've been playing Zookeeper DX on my android phone. I'm not sure if there's an ideal strategy. I don't fully understand the scoring system, and I'm figuring it out as I go, but I wonder if I could learn a lot more by asking than trial/error.

What dictates the bonus at the "Break Time"? I've gotten 10k, 30k, and 50k and I don't understand either.

Is it better to get a level complete faster, or collect more animals at the end? (E.G leave one animal uncollected, and get sets of other animals first)

Is there and end, or does it just get increasingly more complex?

Thanks

Comment: Hello @kevingreen, I changed your tagging becasue this question is not platform specific. IOS also has the same game.

Comment: @Emerica. Thanks, this would be my very first post here.

Comment: Wasted bounty as it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point values for catching animals increases after each level

I think the most important thing to do is to pay attention to whatever the lucky animal is.  If you can string together more matches with the lucky animal before you level up - your score will tend to be higher.  Speed is important for chaining together active progressions. From the "How to Play" section it says you can move other animals while the captured ones are clearing out from screen.   You get bonus points for this!

The break time score basically judges how well you did in terms of chaining together active progressions and also how well you did in terms of catching the lucky animal